# Find incoming caller on my twilio number without answering it

Tags: twilio

I own a twilio number. I want to test if a caller can call my twilio number but connect to it. ie. The caller just hears a ringing sound.

My idea is to find the caller's phone number but not incur any expense on the twilio number. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to get caller phone number without answering it?

Answer (score 1):

I compromised on ringing sound. I found this doc in twilio for sending busy signal to the caller.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/reject